# First project in Javascript: NearestNeighbor Calculator

Tags: javascript, beginner

I just finished my first project in Javascript. It takes an array of locations (with coordinates on position 6 and 7) as Input, then the first location is checked against all other locations. After that it takes the closest neighbor and adds it to the route. Then it takes the coordinates of the neighbor which it just found and does same for it (excluding locations that already have a connection). In the end it returns to the starting point. Please give me some hints how i can write better, cleaner and more readable code. Any feedback is appreciated.

```js
var listCoordinates = [
  [1, "München", "Robert-Bürkle-Straße", "1", 85737, "Ismaning", 48.229035, 11.686153, 524, 854],
  [2, "Berlin", "Wittestraße", "30", 13509, "Berlin", 52.580911, 13.293884, 648, 302],
  [3, "Braunschweig", "Mittelweg", "7", 38106, "Braunschweig", 52.278748, 10.524797, 434, 341],
  [4, "Bretten", "Edisonstraße", "2", 75015, "Bretten", 49.032767, 8.698372, 276, 747],
  [5, "Chemnitz", "Zwickauer Straße", "16a", 9122, "Chemnitz", 50.829383, 12.914737, 622, 525],
  [6, "Düsseldorf", "Gladbecker Straße", "3", 40472, "Düsseldorf", 51.274774, 6.794912, 138, 455]
];
//Haversine formula: calulate distance between two locations
const haversineDistance = ([lat1, lon1], [lat2, lon2], isMiles = false) => {
  const toRadian = angle => (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
  const distance = (a, b) => (Math.PI / 180) * (a - b);
  const RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM = 6371;
  const dLat = distance(lat2, lat1);
  const dLon = distance(lon2, lon1);
  lat1 = toRadian(lat1);
  lat2 = toRadian(lat2);
  //Haversine Formula
  const a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2), 2) + Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2), 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
  const c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
  let finalDistance = RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM * c;
  if (isMiles) {
    finalDistance /= 1.60934;
  }
  return finalDistance;
};
//heuristic strict nearest neighbor (points that already have a connection do not get calculated)
function nearestNeighbor(coordinates) {
  var route = {
    msg: '',
    distance: 0,
    route: [0]
  }
  var currentPoint = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= coordinates.length - 2; i++) {
    var nearestNeighbor = {
      key: 0,
      distance: 0
    }
    var pointaLat = coordinates[currentPoint][6],
      pointaLon = coordinates[currentPoint][7];
    for (var j = 0; j <= coordinates.length - 1; j++) {
      if (j != currentPoint) {
        if (!route.route.includes(j)) {
          var pointbLat = coordinates[j][6],
            pointbLon = coordinates[j][7];
          var currentDistance = haversineDistance([pointaLat, pointaLon], [pointbLat, pointbLon], 0);
          if (nearestNeighbor.distance === 0 || nearestNeighbor.distance > currentDistance) {
            nearestNeighbor.key = j;
            nearestNeighbor.distance = currentDistance;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    route.distance += nearestNeighbor.distance;
    route.route.push(nearestNeighbor.key)
    currentPoint = nearestNeighbor.key;
  }
  //return to start point
  var pointaLat = coordinates[0][6],
    pointaLon = coordinates[0][7],
    pointbLat = coordinates[route.route[route.route.length - 1]][6],
    pointbLon = coordinates[route.route[route.route.length - 1]][7];
  route.distance += haversineDistance([pointaLat, pointaLon], [pointbLat, pointbLon], 0);
  route.route.push(0);
  route.distance = Math.round((route.distance + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  route.msg = "Die kürzeste Strecke beträgt " + route.distance + " km";
  return route;
}

console.log(nearestNeighbor(listCoordinates));
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. Actually really nice to see js that's readable. <3

Answer (score 3):

Are you hoping for the arc length around a sphere or the Earth? What about going through the earth in a straight line? Currently your math solves the sphere but not Earth.

The earth has 2 radi that are used to solve the arc length.

```
R = √ [ (r1² * cos(B))² + (r2² * sin(B))² ] / [ (r1 * cos(B))² + (r2 * sin(B))² ]
B = Latitude
R = Radius
r1 = radius at equator
r2 = radius at the poles
```

But your Haversine method is otherwise correct =D

Comment: Isen't the earth a sphere? Thanks for your nice words :) I will try out what you gave me. What do you think of the nearestNeighbor function? It is not to messy?

Comment: @Herbo The earth is a spheroid. Think of a cartoon with a ball spinning really fast, how it becomes fattened -- that's what is happening with the earth because of physics. Nothing about your function is messy. Internal variables that are used for house keeping (especially lengthy math operations) and increase readability don't require descriptive variable names unless it's obvious what it should probably be named (exactly how you did it with dLat and dLon)

Comment: Worth pointing out that Henrik Hansen has a point about the efficiency your program -- I didn't see it because I didn't put this in an editor. If you've calculated the distance from A to B, you don't have to calculate it again from B to A.

Answer (score 2):

> Please give me some hints how i can write better, cleaner and more readable code

.

**Objects: anything else is merely arranging the deck chairs on the Titanic**

```
var listCoordinates = [
  [1, "München", "Robert-Bürkle-Straße", "1", 85737, "Ismaning", 48.229035, 11.686153, 524, 854],
  [2, "Berlin", "Wittestraße", "30", 13509, "Berlin", 52.580911, 13.293884, 648, 302],
  [3, "Braunschweig", "Mittelweg", "7", 38106, "Braunschweig", 52.278748, 10.524797, 434, 341],
  [4, "Bretten", "Edisonstraße", "2", 75015, "Bretten", 49.032767, 8.698372, 276, 747],
  [5, "Chemnitz", "Zwickauer Straße", "16a", 9122, "Chemnitz", 50.829383, 12.914737, 622, 525],
  [6, "Düsseldorf", "Gladbecker Straße", "3", 40472, "Düsseldorf", 51.274774, 6.794912, 138, 455]
];


// if I'm making lots of mistakes identifying the array elements, 
// its because the reader starts off not knowing that the heck the
// this array data is, then it's ripped apart several times, named and
// then renamed. 
// I cannot tell without very careful study and tracing what the heck
// is going on.

var places = []; 
listCoordinates.forEach(place => {
   places.push(
     { order          : place[0],
       city           : place[1],
       street         : place[2],
       doNotKnow      : place[3],
       whatIsThis     : place[4],
       nearestNeighbor : place[5],
       latitude       : place[6],
       longatude      : place[7],
       something      : place[8],
       somethingElse  : place[9]
    }
  ) );


//heuristic strict nearest neighbor (points that already have a connection do not get calculated)

// pass in a place object and use its properties.  
// I'm not going to rewrite this because I cannot tell how/where all these independent
// variables match to the place object.
// The stark contrast after *you* rewrite using coherent, understandable objects will be a huge "a-ha" moment
// in your understanding of readability, understandability,
// and the potential of object oriented coding in general.
```

P.S. write `toString` methods for objects that output the properties - great for debugging.

Comment: i changed the array of arrays to an array of objects (your code ha some problems but my data is beeing fetched from a server with an php script i just changed it there) and i combind it with Henrik Hansens version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Below, I have tried to refactor your code with some inline comments about what and why, I have done it. The overall design and workflow is preserved, so it's in the detail, I have tried to improve and optimize:

```js
var locations = [
  {id: 1, region: "Ismaning/München (Hauptsitz)", street: "Robert-Bürkle-Straße", streetnumber: "1", postcode: 85737, city: "Ismaning", latitude: 48.229035, longitude: 11.686153, xaxis: 524, yaxis: 854},
  {id: 2, region: "Berlin", street: "Wittestraße", streetnumber: "30", postcode: 13509, city: "Berlin", latitude: 52.580911, longitude: 13.293884, xaxis: 648, yaxis: 302},
  {id: 3, region: "Braunschweig", street: "Mittelweg", streetnumber: "7", postcode: 38106, city: "Braunschweig", latitude: 52.278748, longitude: 10.524797, xaxis: 434, yaxis: 341},
  {id: 4, region: "Bretten", street: "Edisonstraße", streetnumber: "2", postcode: 75015, city: "Bretten", latitude: 49.032767, longitude: 8.698372, xaxis: 276, yaxis: 747},
  {id: 5, region: "Chemnitz", street: "Zwickauer Straße", streetnumber: "16a", postcode: 9122, city: "Chemnitz", latitude: 50.829383, longitude: 12.914737, xaxis: 622, yaxis: 525}
];

// HH: I have moved these functions outside of haversineDistance
// in order to keep that function more clear
const RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM = 6371;
function toRadian(angle) { return Math.PI / 180.0 * angle; }
function distance(a, b) { return (Math.PI / 180) * (a - b); }

//Haversine formula: calulate distance between two locations
// HH: This function now takes two point objects as argument
// instead of two arrays/tuples (see also below)
function haversineDistance(ptA, ptB, isMiles = false) {
  const dLat = distance(ptB.lat, ptA.lat);
  const dLon = distance(ptB.lng, ptA.lng);
  const lat1 = toRadian(ptA.lat);
  const lat2 = toRadian(ptB.lat);

  //Haversine Formula
  const a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2), 2) + Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2), 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
  const c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));

  let finalDistance = RADIUS_OF_EARTH_IN_KM * c;
  if (isMiles) {
    finalDistance /= 1.60934;
  }
  return finalDistance;
};

// HH: Name the function after what it does - not after how it does it.
function findShortestPath(coordinates) {
  var route = {
    msg: '',
    distance: 0,
    route: [0]
  }

  // HH: Instead of having pairs of lat, lon an object representing a location/point/position is more readable
      function getPoint(index) {
        return {
          lat: coordinates[index].latitude,
          lng: coordinates[index].longitude
        };
      }



  var currentPoint = 0;
  // HH: You iterate over and over again a lot of indices that has already been handled.
  // Instead it would be more efficient to maintain a set of remaining indices
  let indices = Array.from({ length: coordinates.length - 1 }, (_, i) => i + 1); // we don't want 0 included as it is the first currentPoint

  while (indices.length > 0) {
    var nearestNeighbor = {
      key: 0,
      distance: 0
    };

    let ptA = getPoint(currentPoint);
    for (let j of indices) {
      let ptB = getPoint(j);
      // HH: Because indices only contains not handled indices, you can omit guarding against current point and points in the route
      var currentDistance = haversineDistance(ptA, ptB, 0);
      if (nearestNeighbor.distance === 0 || nearestNeighbor.distance > currentDistance) {
        nearestNeighbor.key = j;
        nearestNeighbor.distance = currentDistance;
      }
    }
    route.distance += nearestNeighbor.distance;
    route.route.push(nearestNeighbor.key);
    // HH: The nearest neighbor is removed from indices
    indices.splice(indices.indexOf(nearestNeighbor.key), 1);
    currentPoint = nearestNeighbor.key;
  }

  //return to start point
  ptA = getPoint(0);
  let ptB = getPoint(route.route[route.route.length - 1]);
  route.distance += haversineDistance(ptA, ptB, 0);

  route.route.push(0);
  route.distance = Math.round((route.distance + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  route.msg = "Die kürzeste Strecke beträgt " + route.distance + " km";
  return route;
}

console.log(findShortestPath(locations));
```

Comment: Personally, I think the distance thing should be kept outside the the namespace because this distance is calculated differently than most other distances.

Comment: @DavidFisher: You maybe right, - I thought like you about it - maybe "distance" isn't just the right name - it's more like a difference in radians per degree.

Comment: arcLength(degreeA, degreeB) but is still missing the radius?

Comment: the idea of making objects need to follow through and make a "complete" object from each entire array. Do this up front the there are no more "disconnected" data and obscure references anywhere.

Comment: @radarbob: Yeah, you're right, I thought of making a proper `class Location { lat, lng }` object, but your `places` does the trick at the same time as holding all the other information - that's even better. I didn't think that far.

Comment: thanks alot that helped me so much, i knew that it was stupid to check a to b and b to a but i couldnt get my head around it.  Now I just need to refactor all my other functions (i also made a heaps permutation algorithm and a mix of nearestNeighbor, clustering, heaps permutation and cartesian product). Once i am done i might show it here again. I also switched to an array of objects so it's more clear what is what.

Comment: i did most of the changes to the other functions but it is so much slower now. around 8 seconds to calculate everything and befor it was 0.6 seconds. should i change my initial post and put there everything before changes and after changes?

Comment: i benchmarked it  and it turns out that your version of the haversineDistance function is round about 19 times slower than my version. how could that be?

Comment: @Herbo: You're right, it's rather slow. I've tested a little, and it seems to be the `getPoint()` function, that is the bottleneck. I've updated my solution with a new version, that's much faster. But  with the object approach we can omit the `getPoint()`thing and work directly on the location objects.

Comment: thanks i will try it out. As i said i have a mix of nearest neighbor, clustering,  heaps permutation and cartesian product which gives me 57600 possible routes to check and i had to wait around 11 second instead of 0.6 seconds.

Comment: I externalized the getPoint function so i can reuse it in my other functions and i also pass the the locations (or centroids in the case of my clusters)array to it.

Comment: *should i change my initial post and put there everything before changes and after changes?*   Never change the original post code. It can make existing answers and comments useless and confusing.